# Footnote in input file - missing number treated as zero

Tags: errors, footnotes, urls, input

Let's say I have a document Foo.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage]{article}
%...
%%Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
%...
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{headings}
%...
\input{bar}
```

and bar.tex:

```
\section*{Bar}
Blah, blah and some such.
Very interesting thing\footnote{\href{http://whatever}}.
More blah.
```

then I get an error on the line with the footnote when trying to parse Foo.tex:

> Missing number, treated as zero. \endgroup ...{http://whatever}}

Removing the footnote will make the error disappear, so my guess is that even though we input the Bar.tex-file, Latex (usign TexLive with Texmaker, btw.) cannot discern the number of preceding `\footnote{...}` commands.

Any way to circumvent this?

Comment: Are you loading `hyperref` package?

Comment: That was indeed the issue (``href`` taking two arguments) can you elaborate on your answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A minimal example reproducing the error is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\footnote{\href{http://whatever}}
\end{document}
```

The solution: `hyperref`'s `\href` has *two* arguments: `\href{URL}{text}`. Either use both or use `\url{URL}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\footnote{\href{http://whatever}{some text}} or\footnote{\url{http://whatever}}
\end{document}
```