# Missing number, treated as zero when renewing enumerate \item and using hyperref

Tags: errors, hyperref, enumerate, compiling, enumitem

When I tried to integrate the answer for my question [How to recognize the enumerate shortlabels in my custom environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512413/how-to-recognize-the-enumerate-shortlabels-in-my-custom-environment) on my thesis document, latex throwed this error:

```
main.tex:26: Missing number, treated as zero
main.tex:26: Missing \endcsname inserted
main.tex:26: Missing number, treated as zero
```

After two hours, I managed to create a minimal example reproducing this error:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\errorcontextlines 10000
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\renewenumerateoptionalitem{%
  \let\itemenumerateoptional\item
  \renewcommand{\item}[1][]{%
      \refstepcounter{enumerateoptionali}% increment the counter
      \itemenumerateoptional[\bfseries##1~\theenumerateoptionali]%
  }%
}

\newlist{enumerateoptional}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumerateoptional]{
    before=\renewenumerateoptionalitem,
    label=\arabic*,
    nosep,
    labelindent=20mm,
    leftmargin=*,
    after=\let\item\itemenumerateoptional,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerateoptional}[1.]
   \item[Some first] item one
   \item[Some second] item two
\end{enumerateoptional}
\end{document}
```

If you run this, you will get the error `main.tex:26: Missing number, treated as zero`. The line 26 is the first `\item[Some first] item one` on the `enumerateoptional` list.

If you comment the line `\usepackage{hyperref}`, everything works fine. You can also comment the line `before=\renewenumerateoptionalitem,` and keep enabled the `hyperref` package and everything will also work fine too.

After looking into the [`hyperref` package code](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/blob/4d949109ba40c6e79c3d6aa92309359486d28718/hyperref.dtx#L10751-L10758) I found this:

```latex
\let\H@item\item
\newcounter{Item}
\def\theHItem{\arabic{Item}}
\def\item{%
  \@hyper@itemfalse
  \if@nmbrlist\@hyper@itemtrue\fi
  \H@item
}
```

It seems `hyperref` is also redefining `\item` to something. How can I integrate the [How to recognize the enumerate shortlabels in my custom environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512413/how-to-recognize-the-enumerate-shortlabels-in-my-custom-environment/) answer with the `hyperref` package?

---

Related questions

1. [How to fix error Missing number, treated as zero](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455666/how-to-fix-error-missing-number-treated-as-zero)
2. [Missing number, treated as zero using BibTeX in IOP template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304979/missing-number-treated-as-zero-using-bibtex-in-iop-template)
3. [conflict between hyperref and enumitem packages (and \refstepcounter)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409432/conflict-between-hyperref-and-enumitem-packages-and-refstepcounter)
4. [Footnote in input file - missing number treated as zero](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256020/footnote-in-input-file-missing-number-treated-as-zero)
5. [Enumeration error after renew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352774/enumeration-error-after-renew)
6. [Missing number, treated as zero <to be read again> \c@list \item f or \item o](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368209/missing-number-treated-as-zero-to-be-read-again-clist-item-f-or-item-o)

Comment: Just move the `\usepackage{hyperref}` to the end of the preamble (just before the `\begin{document}`).  This is really a duplicate of [conflict between hyperref and enumitem packages (and \refstepcounter)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409432/conflict-between-hyperref-and-enumitem-packages-and-refstepcounter), so I will vote to close.